# Date Time is not being pulled from the database where numbers from the same column are being pulled in my report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two columns:

- The first column can only have values 1 or 2.
- if 1, then my second column has a number.
- if 2, then my second column has a Date Time -( something like this 1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM ).

What I am doing:
I have a tablix with 2 columns..
First column is named a and second is named b
under first I want numbers and under second I want the date time. Basically want to split the second column based on what's on first column i.e. 1 or 2

I have used expressions:

```
=IIF(Fields!first_column.Value=1, Fields!second_column.Value,nothing)
```

and for second

```
=IIF(Fields!first_column.Value=2, Fields!Second_column.Value,nothing)
```

it works prefectly for the number and gives result whereas the column where there should be the date time gives blank with no results. I have tried switching them, using numbers on both and using dates on both column. but every attempt the numbers work the date time doesnt work.

If I was too wordy and didnt make sense, please let me know and I can answer your specific qustions.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you draft output sample?

Comment: "Name"    "1" and    "2 "     these are my columns for my output. names pulls values the column 1 pulls values only the column 2 doesn't pull values which are date time AM/PM.

Comment: what is the datatype of `socond_column` in the database?

Comment: The data type for the column is nvarchar and in the same column there are numbers and dates.

Comment: Problem solved. One of my teammates helped me. I was putting those expressions at the value level. But when I just simply put an expression in the group column to pull the first column, which is either 1 or 2 it automatically gave me one more column and separated both the responses as number and date time.